# For loop not working around tikzmath

Tags: tikzmath

I am trying to draw the dynamics of a discrete dynamical system using `Tikz`. I'd like to use a loop to do so, but for some reason it does not perform the `\tkzmath` operations inside the loop. Here's the code with a minimal example. The first figure shows what I'd like to get, while the second one what I'd like to get without having to copy paste the same code 3 times.

```latex
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, line width=1.5]
    \draw[->, line width=1] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$L_t$};
    \draw[->, line width=1] (0,0) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$L_{t+1}$};
    \draw[dashed, line width=1] (0,0) -- (4.2, 4.2)node[right] {$L_{t+1}=L_t$};
    \draw[scale=1,domain=0:5,smooth,variable=\x,blue]  plot ({\x},{1.25*\x^0.5})  node[right] {$L_{t+1}=\phi (L_{t};A)$};

    % Initialize location and do 1 iteration
    \tikzmath{\xt=4.8; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt,0) -- (\xt, \yt);
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);

    % Iterate 3 times to show path
    % 1
    \tikzmath{\xt=\yt; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \xt) --(\xt, \yt);
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);
    % 2
    \tikzmath{\xt=\yt; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \xt) --(\xt, \yt);
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);
    % 3
    \tikzmath{\xt=\yt; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \xt) --(\xt, \yt);
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, line width=1.5]
    \draw[->, line width=1] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$L_t$};
    \draw[->, line width=1] (0,0) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$L_{t+1}$};
    \draw[dashed, line width=1] (0,0) -- (4.2, 4.2)node[right] {$L_{t+1}=L_t$};
    \draw[scale=1,domain=0:5,smooth,variable=\x,blue]  plot ({\x},{1.25*\x^0.5})  node[right] {$L_{t+1}=\phi (L_{t};A)$};

    % Initialize location and do 1 iteration
    \tikzmath{\xt=4.8; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt,0) -- (\xt, \yt);
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);

    % Iterate 3 times to show path
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2}{
        \tikzmath{\xt=\yt; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
        \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \xt) --(\xt, \yt);
        \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem you are seeing stems from the fact that the argument of `\foreach` is a group, and hence `\xt` and `\yt` only get locally updated, and the local update gets "forgotten". One rather blunt way of overcoming this is to make `\xt` and `\yt` global using `\xdef`.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, line width=1.5]
    \draw[->, line width=1] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$L_t$};
    \draw[->, line width=1] (0,0) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$L_{t+1}$};
    \draw[dashed, line width=1] (0,0) -- (4.2, 4.2)node[right] {$L_{t+1}=L_t$};
    \draw[scale=1,domain=0:5,smooth,variable=\x,blue]  plot ({\x},{1.25*\x^0.5})  node[right] {$L_{t+1}=\phi (L_{t};A)$};

    % Initialize location and do 1 iteration
    \tikzmath{\xt=4.8; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt,0) -- (\xt, \yt);
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);

    % Iterate 3 times to show path
    % 1
    \tikzmath{\xt=\yt; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \xt) --(\xt, \yt);
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);
    % 2
    \tikzmath{\xt=\yt; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \xt) --(\xt, \yt);
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);
    % 3
    \tikzmath{\xt=\yt; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \xt) --(\xt, \yt);
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, line width=1.5]
    \draw[->, line width=1] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$L_t$};
    \draw[->, line width=1] (0,0) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$L_{t+1}$};
    \draw[dashed, line width=1] (0,0) -- (4.2, 4.2)node[right] {$L_{t+1}=L_t$};
    \draw[scale=1,domain=0:5,smooth,variable=\x,blue]  plot ({\x},{1.25*\x^0.5})  node[right] {$L_{t+1}=\phi (L_{t};A)$};

    % Initialize location and do 1 iteration
    \tikzmath{\xt=4.8; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt,0) -- (\xt, \yt);
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);

    % Iterate 3 times to show path
    \foreach \x in {0,1,2}{
        \tikzmath{\xt=\yt; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
        \xdef\xt{\xt}\xdef\yt{\yt}
        \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \xt) --(\xt, \yt);
        \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

An arguably less blunt way to go is to (ab?)use the `remember` key that is available for `\foreach`.

```
\documentclass{article}%
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, line width=1.5]
    \draw[->, line width=1] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$L_t$};
    \draw[->, line width=1] (0,0) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$L_{t+1}$};
    \draw[dashed, line width=1] (0,0) -- (4.2, 4.2)node[right] {$L_{t+1}=L_t$};
    \draw[scale=1,domain=0:5,smooth,variable=\x,blue]  plot ({\x},{1.25*\x^0.5})  node[right] {$L_{t+1}=\phi (L_{t};A)$};

    % Initialize location and do 1 iteration
    \tikzmath{\xt=4.8; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt,0) -- (\xt, \yt);
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);

    % Iterate 3 times to show path
    % 1
    \tikzmath{\xt=\yt; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \xt) --(\xt, \yt);
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);
    % 2
    \tikzmath{\xt=\yt; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \xt) --(\xt, \yt);
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);
    % 3
    \tikzmath{\xt=\yt; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \xt) --(\xt, \yt);
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1.5, line width=1.5]
    \draw[->, line width=1] (0,0) -- (6,0) node[right] {$L_t$};
    \draw[->, line width=1] (0,0) -- (0,4.2) node[above] {$L_{t+1}$};
    \draw[dashed, line width=1] (0,0) -- (4.2, 4.2)node[right] {$L_{t+1}=L_t$};
    \draw[scale=1,domain=0:5,smooth,variable=\x,blue]  plot ({\x},{1.25*\x^0.5})  node[right] {$L_{t+1}=\phi (L_{t};A)$};

    % Initialize location and do 1 iteration
    \tikzmath{\xt=4.8; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt,0) -- (\xt, \yt);
    \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);

    % Iterate 3 times to show path
    \foreach \x [remember=\yt as \yt] in {0,1,2}{
        \tikzmath{\xt=\yt; \yt=1.25*\xt^0.5;}
        \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \xt) --(\xt, \yt);
        \draw[->, dotted, line width=1] (\xt, \yt) --(\yt, \yt);
    }
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

(Same output as above.)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks!